# javascript - form validation - disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, setinterval

I'm new to programming so please forgive me if this is a dumb question...

I'm attempting to have javascript (or jquery - not sure of the difference) toggle the 'disabled' property of the submit button based on periodic form validation checks. It works fine when I key everything into the form, but if I copy and paste from the first password field into the second password field, the disabled property isn't removed from the button.

Any help would be very much appreciated...

Javascript...

```
      $(':input').focusin(function(){

       $(this).css('background-color','#AABEFF');

        }).blur(function(){

       $(this).css('background-color','white');
          });

      function check(){

      if (($('#first').val()!="") && ($('#last').val()!="") && ($('#email').val()!="") && ($('#password1').val()!="") &&
      ($('#password2').val()!="") && ($('#phone1a').val()!="") && ($('#phone1b').val()!="") && ($('#phone1c').val()!="")){

           if (($('#password1').val())==($('#password2').val()))
              {
              $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
              }

           else

            {
             $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
      }

        else

            {
             $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
      }

      window.setInterval(check, 200);
```

Form....

```
        <html>
        <head>

          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        </head>

              <body>
                 <div id="back">
                 </div>

                <div id="wrapper">

                        <div id="header">
                         <div id="logout">
                        <?php
                      include 'employer_header.php';
                        ?>

                         </div>

                        </div>

                        <?php
                        include 'employer_menu.php';
                        ?>

                        <div id="feature">
                        </div>
                        <div id="content">

                        <div class="pad">

        <form method="post" action="employer_register_process.php">

        <p>First Name: <br>
        <input id="first" type="text" name="firstname" size="30"><br></p>
        <p>Last Name: <br>
        <input id="last" type="text" name="lastname" size="30"><br></p>
        <p>Phone 1: <br>
        <input id="phone1a" type="text" name="phone1a" style='width:30px' maxlength="3">-
        <input id="phone1b" type="text" name="phone1b" style='width:30px' maxlength="3">-
        <input id="phone1c" type="text" name="phone1c" style='width:40px' maxlength="4"><br></p>
        <p>Phone 2 (Optional): <br>
        <input type="text" name="phone2a" style='width:30px' maxlength="3">-
        <input type="text" name="phone2b" style='width:30px' maxlength="3">-
        <input type="text" name="phone2c" style='width:40px' maxlength="4"><br></p>
        <p>email: <br>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" size="30"><br></p>
        <p>password: <br>
        <input id="password1" type="password" name="pass1" size="30" mask="x"><br></p>
        <p>retype password: <br>
        <input id="password2" type="password" name="pass2" size="30" mask="x"><br></p>


        <p ><input id='submit' type="submit" name='submit' value='register' disabled='disabled'></p>
        </form>

                      </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/register.js"></script>
              </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please reproduce on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, to help us see the code in action without having to recreate it ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not calling your check function.
you should use jquery .keyup() function to check
Here is an example of what your file would look like:

```
$(':input').focusin(function(){

    $(this).css('background-color','#AABEFF');

}).blur(function(){

    $(this).css('background-color','white');

});

function checkForm(){

  if (($('#first').val()!="") && ($('#last').val()!="") && ($('#email').val()!="") && ($('#password1').val()!="") &&
  ($('#password2').val()!="") && ($('#phone1a').val()!="") && ($('#phone1b').val()!="") && ($('#phone1c').val()!="")){

       if (($('#password1').val())==($('#password2').val()))
          {
          $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
          }

       else

        {
         $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
  }

    else

        {
         $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
  }

  $('#password2').keyup(function(){
         checkForm();
  });
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can add a onKeyUp listener to a text field, and make disable, or if the value is correct, enable, the button's disabled property.

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" onkeyup="validate(this)" />
```

JavaScript:

```
   function validate(textfield) {

   var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_button");
   submitButton.disabled = true;
   if(textfield.value == "good") {
          submitButton.disabled = false;
   }
   }
```

Something like that should be good.

Oh, and JQuery is a framework built on top of Javascript.

Comment: Points for providing a *JavaScript* answer (though I've now added the jQuery tag). Not only is this vanilla JS, but it's significantly more concise and elegant than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong with your code but this definitely works and is a better way of doing it:

```
$(':input').focusin(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','#AABEFF');
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).css('background-color','white');
});

$('input').keyup(function(){

    if (($('#first').val()!="") && ($('#last').val()!="") && ($('#email').val()!="") && ($('#password1').val()!="") &&
  ($('#password2').val()!="") && ($('#phone1a').val()!="") && ($('#phone1b').val()!="") && ($('#phone1c').val()!="")) {

        if ( $('#password1').val() == $('#password2').val() ) {
            $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }

    } else {
       $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: If you're going to state *this...works and is a better way*, please provide a clear explanation of *why* it's 'better,' and the problems with the original.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended to be snide, I was simply asking for more, explanatory, information; in order to understand the changes you made to the function/approach posted in the question. My rationale for questioning your assertion that your approach is 'better' is that, without explanation, it's an unsupported assertion, and potentially inflammatory/provocative, without the context of 'why.' Also, SO is here to educate/teach others; and the *why* is important to that end.

Comment: _why_ is in the code I post. However, in retrospect it is probably best to use the keyup event instead and I have amended my answer to represent this.

Comment: No, the code you posted shows *what* you did and shows the approach you took; it says *nothing* about the *why*. I get the impression, however, that this is something we're unlikely to agree on, so I'll not pursue further (albeit I'm willing to do so, I'm not trying to be rude or offensive about things). And, as a closing note, yes: I'd imagine that `keyup` is the better approach for this, since it responds more quickly and obviously.